# como hago para llamar un archivo php desde un boton

Tags: javascript

```
<?php

$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
include 'conexion_be.php';
$nombre_completo = $_POST['nombre_completo'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];

$query = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre_completo, correo,usuario, contrasena)
          VALUES('$nombre_completo','$correo','$usuario','$contrasena')";

$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

if($ejecutar){
    echo '
    <script>
    alert("Usuario registrado exitosamentre"); 
    </script>
    ';
}
```

?>

ese es el archivo php que quiero ejecutar

```
btn_enviar1.addEventListener("click",()=>{irA(registroMascota);});
```

esta es la accion que ejecuta el boton me envia a otra section

```
<a  class="boton"    href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn_enviar1" >Guardar</a>
```

y este es el boton

necesito que llamar el archivo php cuando le doy al boton para insertar lo datos en la tabla

Comment: Una palabra: AJAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### AJAX Es la solución

Por sus siglas, **Asynchronous JavaScript And XML** es una técnica para tener comunicación en segundo plano con el servidor

En Javascript, para usar AJAX, usamos [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), el cual es un método para establecer una conexión asíncrona en segundo plano con el servidor

---

#### Sintaxis de `fetch`

Este método recibe dos parámetros, uno requerido y otro opcional

```
fetch(string: url, object: request_options) : promise
```

Es decir, que requiere de la URL a la cual se va a hacer la petición, el parámetro de la configuración es opcional, si no se provee, simplemente se hará una petición de tipo *GET*

---

#### Enviando una petición

Como `fetch` nos devuelve una [promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), podemos usar el método `.then` y `.catch`, donde `.then` es para resolver la promesa y ejecutar código en caso de que la petición sea exitosa y `.catch` es para obtener errores en la petición

```
fetch("miarchivo.php").then(r => r.text())
```

Aquí tenemos el **método de conversión de `then`**, son dos métodos distintos

- `.text()` para cuando la petición solo devolverá texto
- `.json()` si la respuesta del servidor tiene una estructura JSON

Una vez entendido esto, podemos pasar a el siguiente punto

---

#### Obteniendo la respuesta

Si el servidor envía una respuesta, la podemos obtener después del primer `.then`

```
fetch("miarchivo.php").then(r => r.text()).then(response => {
    // Donde response es la respuesta del servidor
    console.log(response);
});
```

---

#### Obteniendo errores

Si la petición tiene errores, puedes comprobarlos con el método `.catch`, el cual es único para recibir errores

```
fetch(...)...
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

---

#### Solución

```
btn_enviar1.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    fetch("archivo.php").then(r => r.text()).then(response => {
        irA(registroMascota);
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(e => {
        alert("Error "+e);
    });
});
```

---

#### Enviando datos con POST

Para enviar datos con el método *POST*, podemos usar el segundo parámetro de `fetch`, el cual es la configuración de la petición

```
btn_enviar1.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    const fd = new FormData(); // Necesario para enviar datos
    fd.append("nombre", "valor"); // Datos a enviar
    fetch("archivo.php", {body:fd, method:"POST"}).then(r => r.text()).then(r => {
        irA(registroMascota);
    });
});
```

---

#### Notas

- AJAX **NO** es un método para hacer cambios en tiempo real, llenar al servidor de peticiones ocasionará su caída
- En la antigüedad, también existía otro método para AJAX, el cual era [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), sigue estando disponible con menos uso
- En tu archivo PHP, no añadas `<script>`, ya que vamos a imprimir eso en el lado del cliente, no vamos a modificar el DOM

---

Comment: de que forma puedo hacer de que los datos los coja con post ya que me guarda pero debido a que por defecto se envían en Get no me guarda estos datos

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo me ayudaste mucho

Answer (score 0):

LA SOLUCION COMPLETA

el index

´´´´´´

```
<section id="registro" class="ocultar" >
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="volver" id="btn_volver"><span class="material-icons cl-black">
  arrow_back
  </span></a>
  <div class="panel-central-img">
     <a href=""><img src="../img/dog-labrador-icon.png" alt="splash" border=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-central-reducido">
     <input type="text"  placeholder="Nombre Completo" name="nombre_completo" id="nombre_completo">
    </div>
  <div class="panel-central-reducido">
      <input type="text"  placeholder="Correo Electronico"  name="correo" id="correo">
  </div>
  <div class="panel-central-reducido">
      <input type="text"  placeholder="Usuario" name="usuario" id="usuario">
  </div>
  <div class="panel-central-reducido">
      <input type="password"  placeholder="Contraseña" name="contrasena" id="contrasena">
  </div>
  <div class="panel-central-reducido">
  <a  class="boton" href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn_enviar1" >Guardar</a>
  </div>
```

el js

```
btn_enviar1.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  const fd = new FormData();
  var nombre_completo=document.getElementById("nombre_completo").value;
  var correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
  var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
  var contrasena = document.getElementById("contrasena").value;

  fd.append("nombre_completo", nombre_completo); 
  fd.append("correo", correo );
  fd.append("usuario", usuario );
  fd.append("contrasena", contrasena );
  fetch("../php/registro_usuario_be.php", {body:fd, method:"POST"}).then(r => r.text()).then(r => {
      irA(registroMascota);

      alert("Registro exitiso");
  });
```

});

la conexión a la base de datos

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login_register_db");
```

el php para el registro

```
<?php

include 'conexion_be.php';
$nombre_mascota = $_POST['nombre_mascota'];
$edad = $_POST['edad'];
$raza = $_POST['raza'];


$query = "INSERT INTO mascotas(nombre_mascota, edad, raza)
          VALUES('$nombre_mascota','$edad','$raza')";



$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

?>

Comment: En vez de publicar tu solución como otra respuesta, deberías marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te sirvió, así otros usuarios con problemas similares sabrán que también les puede ser útil.

Comment: si , ya la había marcado como correcta amigo